# Kong Api Gateway - How to setup authentication flows

Tags: authentication, microservices, api-gateway, kong

I don't have much experience with api gateways. I've looked into (and setup) Kong with some auth mechanisms. For all of these the user details are added to Kong through their admin API.

How do I setup a complex authentication flow with Kong. i.e: A user registers, some custom business code is run to validate the user then an email is sent to them for confirmation.

The only way I see is having a microservice which talks to the admin api. The UI would then simply talk to this microservice (which would in turn add users to the admin api), am I on the right path?

Answer (score 1):

Using Kong Admin API you could [create API consumers](https://docs.konghq.com/0.14.x/getting-started/adding-consumers/) which then you can add authentication methods to (JWT, auth0 ...).

The way I have always implemented this was through my backend talking to the kong admin. of course, this means all your backend application then have access to the kong admin fully but that can be prevented by either having a proxy service on top of kong admin which only allows consumer creation and auth management (technically this can be your user service) or add kong admin to kong as a service and restrict the use cases (less secure since any mistakes might expose your admin API).

One thing you should definitely avoid is to access kong admin directly from your frontend app.